# How to count rows from one table using multiple tables in FROM clause and some search conditions in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a QUERY which is like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt 
    FROM tbl_docatrtypegroupdoctype, 
         tbl_doctype, 
         tbl_docatrtypegroup 
    WHERE 1=1  
          AND 
         (tbl_doctype.doctype_name like '%Payment%' 
            OR tbl_doctype.doctype_name like'% Payment' 
            OR tbl_doctype.doctype_name like ' Payment%' ) 
    LIMIT 1
```

Now in the above query I need to count the number of records in table "tbl_docatrtypegroupdoctype" under the conditons given in where clause, whenever i execute the query, I get 77 count, but actual count in DB is 12.

What could be the problem with this query and how can I rectify it?

Ant help will be appriciated

Thanks

Comment: A question, why you are using these 3 'like'? Given that the first one does the job (if the tbl_doctype.doctype_name begins, ending our have the word Payment)?

Comment: Its like starting from ending into and similar to

Comment: As pmariano said, the first one covers the other two

Comment: Gotchaaa i understood will correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your join conditions. What happens if you don't is a cross product which is not what you want.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM tbl_docatrtypegroupdoctype JOIN  
     tbl_doctype on (THE CONDITION) JOIN 
     tbl_docatrtypegroup on (THE CONDITION)
```

Alternatively the JOIN conditions can be spefified in the WHERE clause.

---

In the where clause:

```
  WHERE table1.field1 = table2.field2 AND table2.field3 = table3.field4
```

The fields that you join on must be semantically related in some way of course.

Comment: How It can be used in Where Clause?

Comment: Don't use the where clause joins (know as implicit joins). Use explicit joins and you will never have accidental cross joins again. It is a poor practice to use implicit joins.

Comment: You need to do some reading to understand joins, if you don't understand them you are not qualified to query a database. try this link as a start (I know it's for SQL server but join theory is the same for all databases)http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4785

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply all join-conditions between the three tables.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have three tables that are linked to each other somehow. No database does the linking automatically. You must add some AND-expressions and link the tables.